# MPFB character has matted hair and blue eyes

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects, hair, makehuman

everyone.
I have a little problem. I'm using the MakeHuman MPFB2 add-on to create human characters in Blender. It is great! But one problem I have encountered with it is that, my African/Black characters tend to get blue eyes and matted hair and I don't know how to correct that. I'm concerned about the blue eyes because I mainly create African/Black characters.

How do I add brown eyes instead of blue eyes? Also, how do I get rid of the matted hair? I've provided a screengrab below. Thanks.

Please, I've solved the problem. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Hi there! If you have solved the problem you can post the solution as an answer so other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

The matted hair is due to a roughness setting in the material. All mesh objects created/handled by MPFB, with the exception of skin and eyes, have a principled node as a centerpiece.

You should be able to simply change the roughness value to make it look more to your liking:

[image: Roughness can be changed in material settings]

Eyes in MPFB are completely procedural. You can change color, as well as several other settings, freely. This, too, in the material settings:

[image]